# Importing JWT in my React-Native app breaks the app

Tags: react-native, jwt, expo, app-store-connect-api

I'm trying to connect to the app store API in my react native app, but anytime I try to import a JWT pacakge to sign the token, I get a package error.  Here is my code and the error I get

```
import * as JSW from 'jose'; //json web token signer

export default class appStoreAPI {

    private static _instance:appStoreAPI;
    static get I() {
        if(!this._instance) this._instance = new appStoreAPI();
        return this._instance;
    }

    token_creations = () => {

        const credentials = {
            privateKey: 'my private key', 
            apiKeyId: 'api from app store',
            issuerId: 'issuer id from app store'
        }

        let now = Math.round((new Date().getTime()/1000));
        let nowPlus20 = now + 1999 

        let token = {
            header: {
                "alg":"ES256",
                "kid": credentials.apiKeyId,
                "typ": "JWT"
            },

            payload: {
                "iss": credentials.issuerId,
                "iat": now,
                "exp": nowPlus20,
                "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1",
                "scope": [
                    "GET /v1/apps?filter[platform]=IOS"
                ]
            },

        }

        const token_sign = new JSW.SignJWT(token)
        }


    }
```

And I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: crypto
```

I've npm installed crypto already

If I comment out the JWT import, then this error goes away.  I am also using expo.  Not sure if I'm signing this token correctly either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`jose`](https://github.com/panva/jose#supported-runtimes)'s own readme does not mention react-native as a supported runtime. react-native is missing (and [not planning](https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/83) for) a Web Cryptography API implementation

It's a shame because it is a sought after runtime for `jose`, but without the runtime having a basic set of interoperable Web APIs there's nothing much I can do to support it.